# Visual Studio Local DB Issue

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am unsure about how to best resolve this issue. I have been working on a MVC application that requires user authentication, so I set up the project to use individual accounts, all well and good, it works fine.

However it saves the account data into a local db instance. I am at the stage where I want to host the application on a amazon web server I am renting. Publishing it to here has been fine, but now it can't connect to the local db so the sign up / register is no longer working.

My question is, can I somehow take this local db with me to the server, or do I need to generate a SQL script from it and deploy it on a local instance of SQL Express, and if so, how? I have had no luck with my attempts at either and would greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this as Local DB is not recommended for anything in production so I'm not sure if it's allowed in AWS. In Visual Studio at the top of the solution explorer window there is a button to "Show all files" you should then see the hidden MDF local db file within the App_Data folder. Ensure that this file is being published to AWS.